# How do i Set the multiple initial route for android in flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, git, kotlin, dart

I made an application clone app. When the application is run, a clone App is also run. I want to open the home screen from the clone app and log in from the original app
how is it possible?

I made Two Main Activities in Android. In one Flutter initial route is given in the home and in the other login
Declare MainActivitya and MainActivity in the Manifest